# predict from a Cox model with beta coefficients

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, regression-strategies

I fitted a Cox PH model in R with the survival package and the `coxph` function.
I get the beta estimates from this model.
How can I use these coefficients to manually predict on new data, like the predict function does.

In a linear regression this is just the matrix multiplication `X %*% beta` if $X$ is the data and $beta$ is the vector of coefficients.

How is this in the Cox model? I also see that predict has several options for types of predictions.

here is a minimal example:

```
library(survival)
data("ovarian")
m <- coxph(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~., data=ovarian)
```

these two give different results:

```
head(as.matrix(ovarian[, -c(1:2)]) %*% m$coefficients)

      [,1]
1 10.102002
2 10.371810
3  9.706097
4  6.820160
5  7.357138
6  7.627324

head(predict(m, ovarian))
          1           2           3           4           5           6 
 2.66935119  2.93915962  2.27344680 -0.61249088 -0.07551308  0.19467374
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the discrepancy is due to the fact that predict function in package survival does not yield x*beta but (x-mean)*beta.

Answer (score 2):

It would be good to understand the model from an algebraic standpoint.  To help in understanding and to handle complexities such as categorical predictors, nonlinearity and interaction, the R `rms` package provides two ways to represent a fitted model algebraically.  The big step is to get the linear predictor $X\hat{\beta}$ then you need to turn that into things like median survival time and Prob$(T > t | X)$, i.e., survival probabilities.

The `cph` function is a front-end to `coxph`, and if you have $\LaTeX$ on your system and you type `latex(f)` where `f` is the fit object result from `cph`, you'll get the full form of the fitted model in terms of survival probabilities.  If you don't have $\LaTeX$ you can use `Function(f)` to get the full algebraic form in R notation, but just for the linear predictor.

Comment: thanks. When I fit the model in `cph` and use the `latex` command I get an output that only prints the linear predictor $X\beta$, the same I cant get with `coef(fit)` and does not help me.

Comment: Tell me how you installed $\LaTeX$ and how did you make the system aware of where the $\LaTeX$ executables are.

Comment: I use TeXlive on a linux system. Here is what I get for the ovarian dataset from survival package: http://i.imgur.com/R5asEzF.png

Comment: Excellent.  You may have too specity `surv=TRUE` to `cph` to get $S_{0}(t)$ defined in the output.  Also see the `cph` `time.inc` argument.

Comment: thanks, that works. I now have $S(t)$ for the intervals and can calculate the survival probabilities at time $t$ for each person. However, that is not exactly what I want, and it's not what `predict` does (I do not specify any $t$s). I just want to manually reproduce these values: `fit <- coxph(...); preds <- predict(fit, newdata)`

Comment: Then what you want is the linear predictor $X\hat{\beta}$ from that output, which is the default output from `predict`.

Comment: the output of `predict` and `X\beta` are not the same, but obviously the ranks are so `survConcordance(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ as.matrix(ovarian[, -c(1:2)]) %*% mm$coefficients, ovarian); 
survConcordance(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ predict(mm, ovarian), ovarian)` yields the same results

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example that I can use to get to the bottom of that.  Simulate a tiny dataset or use a built-in (to R or survival) dataset.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Thanks.  I see that you did not add the centering constant when you did the manual calculation.  For `cph` this is `fitobject$center`; not sure about `coxph`.